# error when trying to install body-parser

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm

im trying to install body-parser into my project but i get an error:

```
npm install body-parser  --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ 
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body
npm ERR! error installing body-parser@1.0.2
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: raw-body@'>=1.1.2- <1.2.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.1.0"]
```

im using npm 1.1.4 , node 0.6.12 on Ubunto.

Comment: Did you installing the latest version npm install body-parser

Comment: It looks to me you are doing npm install body-parser@1.0.2, which tells npm to specifically install body parser version 1.0.2 and then your log says No compatible version found for 1.0.2
So if you do npm install body-parser, it will install the latest version avaiable on github.

Comment: im just doing npm install body-parser

Comment: then check npm-debug-log file

Comment: where is it located ?

Comment: Node 0.6.12??? Is there a reason for this ancient version or did you just never update node again? If the latter - maybe try that (current Version is 0.10.31)

Comment: i just installed node actually.. no idea why it installed such an old version. how do you update node to the latest version ??

Comment: sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

Comment: tried that.. got an error on the last command :  Error: invalid version 0.10.31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I check https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/package.json, the latest version is 1.6.5 that require node  version >= 0.8

but on your console, you request body-parser version 1.0.2,

so i think this is problem with your node version, try to install newer version on node, or use nave to manage your node version

Answer (score -2):

Please try

npm config set proxy null